# Determine Solaris server model inside a zone?

Tags: solaris, solaris-zones

I'm a DBA doing some inventory and as part of it, I gather some system info.  I'm wondering if it's possible to determine what hardware a zone is running on if you only have access to the zone?

I think the answer is "no" because you can't run prtdiag.  prtconf also is not available (to any usable extent).

Most of what I need (number of cpus, amount of RAM, OS release, etc.) I can get, so this is a bit of icing on the cake to say "it's on an M5000" or whatever.  Works fine from a true physical but I think the info is unavailable in a zone.  Anything I missed?  Thanks!

Comment: I think if you do find a way to do what you need it should be reported to Oracle as a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum that you could from Solaris zone - to learn server family name via processor type.
For example, this is something from **SPARC T7-*** family:

```
user@zone:~$ psrinfo -vp
   The physical processor has 6 virtual processors (16-21)
     SPARC-M7 (chipid 0, clock 4133 MHz)
```

and you could only guess if it is primary or guest LDOM.

Also you could find some information about connected to LDOM disks via iostat:

```
user@zone:~$ iostat -En
   ssd2             Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0 
   Vendor: HITACHI  Product: OPEN-V      -SUN Revision: 8301 Serial No: 50413A37000E 
   Size: 214.75GB <214749020160 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
   Illegal Request: 1343 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0 Non-Aligned Writes: 0 
   ssd3             Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 6 Transport Errors: 6 
   Vendor: HITACHI  Product: OPEN-V      -SUN Revision: 8301 Serial No: 50413A37000D 
   Size: 483.18GB <483183820800 bytes>
   Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
   Illegal Request: 1343 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0 Non-Aligned Writes: 0
```

But there is no guarantee that this is full list of connected devices to physical server, because there may be several LDOMs on it.

PS/
If you have root access to LDOM, you may use virtinfo command to learn some parent machine information (you could not use it in zone):

```
root@ldom:~# virtinfo -a
Domain role: LDoms guest I/O
Domain name: domain1
Domain UUID: 8dff4050-8f62-4db5-b5b1-b14023fc058a
Control domain: physical-server-name.local
Chassis serial#: AK00000000
```